# Push notification from app using Parse Sdk

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, message

I am sending push notification to a specific user using parse sdk? 
Problem is , if receiver user's app is running at the time of sending the notification then it is working fine , but if receiver app is not running at the time of sending push notification, it does not receive any push badge or alert. whats wrong am I doing ? Please see the code.`    PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];

```
[pushQuery whereKey:Key_UserName equalTo:self.selectedBuddy.userName];

PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:ClassName_Message];
object[Message_MessageText] = txtFieldMessage.text;
object[Message_SenderName] = applicationDelegate.userInfo.userName;
object[Message_ReceiverName] = self.selectedBuddy.userName;
[object saveInBackground];

NSDictionary *data = @{
                       Message_MessageText : txtFieldMessage.text,
                       Message_SenderName : applicationDelegate.userInfo.userName,
                       Message_ReceiverName : self.selectedBuddy.userName
                       };

// Send push notification to query
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:pushQuery]; // Set our Installation query
[push  setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackground];
`
```

Comment: If the user gets it while in foreground then it's not a problem with your push syntax. You need to verify you followed the procedures in properly subscribing users to push notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you aren't setting up the push query correctly, you need to query for an installation..

Need a setup like this:

```
PFQuery *usernameQuery = [PFUser query];
                    [usernameQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:aName];
                    PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
                    [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:usernameQuery];
```

You also have to make sure that you have a username field in your installation, i.e each time a user logs in you need:

```
 PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
                    installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
                    [installation saveInBackground];
```

Could also be a problem that you don't have "alert" in your data dictionary. I think that is a required key if you want the push to work correctly, try:

```
NSDictionary *data = @{@"alert": txtFieldMessage.text, Message_SenderName : applicationDelegate.userInfo.userName, Message_ReceiverName : self.selectedBuddy.userName, @"sound": @“”};
```

Comment: But why app receiver app receive the notification when it is running.

Comment: try this NSDictionary *data = @{@"alert": txtFieldMessage.text, Message_SenderName : applicationDelegate.userInfo.userName,
                       Message_ReceiverName : self.selectedBuddy.userName, @"sound": @“”};